# Magento empty page in checkout/cart

Tags: magento

Got a problem with adding products to the cart, it goes to the checkout page but the page is empty apart from the surrounding header/footer template.

Ive tried everything i can think of, its not the theme (happens on all themes), i tried diabling compiler and flushing caches etc..

No errors in the server log, i have another magento installation on the same server and that is working fine. Tried disabling all 3rd party extensions too.

Any other places i can look? Im lost!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If header/footer exists it means that script worked from start till end, but might be with some errors. Generally you should first of all try to look for all `remove` directives in your layout xml files(`grep` helps). It might be that the content area is simply removed by some xml.

In case XML way thing didn't worked, the things are getting tougher. You should check every template file which should be rendered in the `content`. it might be that content is somehow commented out.

The other thing to consider is, as far as I remember, the `content block` should have `type list` or `output="toHtml"` so it would be rendered automatically.

At the moment that's all what I might think off. Oh ya! And check that checkout module is enabled and it's output also enabled!

To check if module enabled you should open the `Mage_Checkout.xml` or `Mage_Cart.xml` and check if the both enabled at all.

After that in admin panel there is such page as `Disable Modules Output` where the output of the cart module might be disabled.

**Very important note!**

Make sure you **disable** all custom modules and **not simply disable their output**. Because in latter case you will have module working, simply with no output.

Comment: Oh my god, i wasted two days on this and the checkout module was disabled. How? I have no idea! I dont rmember disabling it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Wow me too. It was disabled in my store but not at default. No idea how that got set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check in configuration > advanced

Make sure you check the mage_checkout is enabled both on default but also (more importantly) at your store level (adjust global scope in the top left).

Chances are mage_checkout could just be disabled at your store level for some reason.